# How to set a length of an array of byte array in .Net C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I would like to have an array of byte arrays.

If I have an array of `int`, I can set a length of it with this:

```
var array = new int[12];
```

But if I try this with `byte[]`, it doesn't work:

```
var bytesArray = new byte[][12];
```

How can I define an array of byte arrays?

(In the moment, I try to define this, I don't know the individual length of the single byte arrays.)

Comment: `new byte[12][]` - array of `12` items each of them is an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new byte[12][]`, as discussed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way `var bytesArray = (byte[][])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(byte[]), 12);` using [Array.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?view=net-7.0).